# Sum of values based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
    ID        change         SX      Supresult
0  UNITY        NaN           0        NaN
1  UNITY    -0.009434        100     -0.015283 (P1)
2  UNITY     0.003463         0        NaN
3  TRINITY   0.008628        100     -0.043363 
4  TRINITY  -0.027374        100      0.008423 (P2)
5  TRINITY  -0.011002         0        NaN
6  TRINITY  -0.004987        100       NaN
7  TRINITY   0.007566         0        NaN
```

I use the following program which creates a new column 'Supresult' if 'SX' is equal to 100. The new column stores the sum of **NEXT** three 'change' values. For instance in index 1 the supresult is a sum of change in index 2,3 & 4.

```
df['Supresult'] = df[df.SX == 100].index.to_series().apply(lambda x: df.change.shift(-1).iloc[x: x + 3].sum())
```

However, I am facing two problems that I need assistance with:

(P1): I want the sum to be 'ID' specific. For instance the result in index 1 goes ahead and take the sum of one value from UNITY and two from TRINITY. Sum should be made as long as it in within the same 'ID'. I tried to add `.groupby('ID')` at the end of my code but it gave a keyerror.

(P2): Since the index 3 already gave sum of next three change, index 4 shouldn't go ahead and make the sum of the next three days. The next sum should only be taken once the previous calculation period is complete i.e.  index 6 and onwards.

Intended result:

```
    ID        change         SX      Supresult
0  UNITY        NaN           0        NaN
1  UNITY    -0.009434        100       NaN
2  UNITY     0.003463         0        NaN
3  TRINITY   0.008628        100     -0.043363 
4  TRINITY  -0.027374        100       NaN
5  TRINITY  -0.011002         0        NaN
6  TRINITY  -0.004987        100       NaN
7  TRINITY   0.007566         0        NaN
```

Little help will be appreciated, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Given your complex requirements, I think a loop is appropriate:

```py
# If your data frame is not indexed sequentially, this will make it so.
# The algorithm needs the frame to be indexed 0, 1, 2, ...
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Every row starts off in "unconsumed" state
consumed = np.repeat(0, len(df))
result = np.repeat(np.nan, len(df))

for i, sx in df['SX'].iteritems():
    # The next three rows
    slc = slice(i+1, i+4)

    # A row is considered a match if:
    #   * It has SX == 100
    #   * The next three rows have the same ID
    #   * The next three rows are not involved in a previous summation
    match = (
        (sx == 100) and
        (df.loc[slc, 'ID'].nunique() == 1) and
        (consumed[i] == 0)
    )
    if match:
        consumed[slc] = 1
        result[i] = df.loc[slc, 'Supresult'].sum()

df['Supresult'] = result
```

Comment: Does the code work at ur end? it spits out " KeyError: 'Supresult' " for me